# Provide custom back navigation with fragment in kotlin

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, navigation

I'm trying to implement OnBackPressedCallback
I followed the explanation here

https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back

but it's incomplete

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_showFragment_to_homeFragment)
        }

        //callback.handleOnBackPressed()
    }
```

if i try to implement OnBackPressedCallback it's not ok

```
class ShowFragment : Fragment(), OnBackPressedCallback() {
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution

```
       val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_showFragment_to_homeFragment)
        }

        requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(
            this, 
            callback
        )
```